# WPF C# update-database Connection defaulting to localDb not SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, wpf, dbcontext

The solution comprises a WPF (.Net Framework) application called App.UI, and a >Net Framework Class Library, named App.Data

I'm attempting to update my existing database following the first Migration, however, the update-database is defaulting to the localDb\mssqllocaldb and creating/updating the Db there instead of the existing database I have provided in the App.Data App.config file.

The update-database command should simply create a new schema in the database and create tables within that database/schema.

In the app.config  of the App.Data class library I have added the following
**AppDb is an existing Database

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="AppDB"
         connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=AppDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The constructor in AppDbContext is as follows

```
public AppDbContext() : base("AppDb")
{

}
```

I've researched previous questions on this and read online but cannot find a solution to this problem.

I've not added the connection string to the App.UI WPF project due to conflicting information I've read.  It would be nice to know also if the connection string should be included in both the App.UI WPF project and the App.Data class Library.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be nice to know also if the connection string should be included in both the App.UI WPF project and the App.Data class Library.

The connection string should be added to the configuration file for the executable application, i.e. in the `App.config` file for the WPF application project (App.UI).

You should not define connection strings in the class library. These won't be looked up by the `Configuration` class.

Answer (score -2):

found an answer to this issue.

I tried the answer provided by mm8 but received an error message that no connection string was defined.

I've now added the connection string to both the .UI project and the .Data class library.

Also I had to update the Startup project settings in Visual Studio by selecting the 'Multiple startup projects' option, and setting the 'Action' for both the App.UI project and App.Data library to 'Start'.

The Database was then correctly updated as expected with the new schema and tables added.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The connection string in the class library is not used so you might as well remove it. Why define it in two places?

Comment: Connection string is only need to be defined in a runtime application. You got an error probably because you didn't rebuild application with new app.config in .UI project.